# Class "phpseclib\Crypt\RSA" not found

Tags: laravel

I am doing laravel project and all the time I am facing this issue **Class "phpseclib\Crypt\RSA" not found and How to solve it ??**  In the composer.json has this

```
"require": {
        "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
        "darryldecode/cart": "^4.2",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.75",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^2.11",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
        "league/omnipay": "^3.2",
        "omnipay/paypal": "^3.0",
        "phpseclib/phpseclib": "^3.0",
        "paragonie/random_compat": "^2.0"
    }, 
In the controller has already imported "use phpseclib\Crypt\RSA;" Please help me!!!
```

I wanna solve this issue in my project **Class "phpseclib\Crypt\RSA" not found.**